# C++ Assign std::map values with enum class object

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, typedef, unordered-map

Consider following code.
In my real case scenario i have somthing like that:

```
typedef enum
{
    vehicle,
    computer,

} Article;
```

And that is what I'm trying to construct:

```
enum class status{
    notPaid,
    paid,
};


struct S {
    status status_vehicle;
    status status_computer;

    std::map<Article, status> mymap =
    {
        {vehicle,  S::status_vehicle},
        {computer, S::status_computer},
    };
};

int main ()
{   
    Article a1 = vehicle;
    S::mymap.at(a1) = status::paid; // this line doesn't work
}
```

However, the last line (`S::mymap.at(a1) = status::paid`;) is not working. I've tried different approaches, using the `find()` function of `std::map` for example. I got the error "assignment of member `std::pair<Article, status>::second` in read only object".

Does someone know, how to do that? Also maybe how to design the whole in a better way? (the whole from the line  "And that is what I'm trying to construct").
Also I would have prefer to use an `unordered_map` instead of a `map` but was not working. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this is the right code? I get "fatal error: invalid use of non-static data member 'mymap'", which makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `mymap` is not static.

You can do like this:

```
Article a1 = vehicle; 
struct S mystruct;
mystruct.mymap.at(a1) = status::paid;
```

Or add `static` to your member in struct:

```
struct S {
    status status_vehicle;
    status status_computer;

    static std::map<Article, status> mymap;
};
```

But when using static, you have to initialize `mymap` outside declaration of `struct S` and member that you can't use non-static members of struct

```
std::map<Article,status> S::mymap={
    {vehicle,S::status_vehicle}
};
```

> A static member is shared by all objects of the class. All static data
>   is initialized to zero when the first object is created, if no other
>   initialization is present

And logically is not good in your example

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static

Comment: Please quote or rewrite the relevant information from your links. Link-only answers are cumbersome and volatile.

Comment: You can't use the name 'struct' there since 'struct' is a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

Since `myMap` is non-static, it cannot be assigned as static variables are.
You can change your code like this:

```
int main ()
{   
    Article a1 = vehicle; 
    S ss;
    ss.mymap.at(a1) = status::paid;    
}
```